# MY USB3 Card is preventing my computer from sleeping. How can I stop it?

Tags: usb, sleep

Whenever I try to put my computer to sleep, it wakes up instantly. I have found out it is the USB 3 card I recently purchased which is the problem, as when I disable it in Device Manager my computer sleeps fine. Any ideas? I have tried most of the power options as well.

The driver is a ASMedia XHCI Controller. Generic USB 3 PCI-e card.

Comment: So you have ensured "Allow this device to wake the computer" is UNchecked?  Does it behave the same with no USB devices plugged into it?